# Want to create an app, but don't know how to save the data

Tags: java, android, save, cloud

I want to create a social app, where people can interact with each other. I'm going to need to be able to save the users data in a way that other people could retrieve it and look at it. I know that you can save data on the phone with files or shared preferences but I don't think that would work with what I'm trying to do. Could I use the cloud to do this? Or would I have to use a server or something like it. I'm fairly new to android programming, so i'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: If you're that new to programming, you should probably start with some simpler projects first.

Comment: I've made an application before, but it didn't utilize anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save user data in many ways that you want to do it! Saving the user's data must be the top most priority for the service that lets users chat and talk. Because a user data makes it a *social* application. If you keep loosing or deleting the data it would cause a havoc among the users and they would leave your application.

#### If Cloud and Android, use Google Cloud

There are several ways of doing that, in the Mobile Application field. Since it is Android, you can always use Google Cloud. Google Cloud lets you have its API and would take care of most of the applications itself and you would have to just stylize your application and handle just a few things.

https://cloud.google.com/

#### Understand the Cloud

But wait, using Cloud is not that much simple. You first need to understand what Cloud Networking actually is.

### Techniques

And yes, never save data on the User's phone if you want to save the data permanently. Otherwise you can save the data on the user's phone while they interact.

#### Save data on Users' Device

One example of this project (application) where the data is stored on the Users' phones is WhatsApp. They don't save the message or photos on their server or any service related to them. Users' phone gets a Database created to store the data.

#### Save data online.

But like Facebook Messenger, the messages are stored on the Server of Facebook where they story the details and data and each user gets the messages sent to them even if they get a new phone or a new everything!

It totally depends on your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking that when people would save their profile information and picture, it could be saved on a server or something so other people could load it on their phone and view it. That's all I really need to save. What if their was something similar to facebooks wall where you could post something and everybody could see it. I'm guessing that that would have to be saved on a server, right?

Comment: @user3741413, exactly! Everything that others can see anytime they visit or from what so ever browser or device they visit must be able to see, should be saved on your public server. This would help others to get the data whenever and from whereever they want it to. Otherwise a simple _by mistake_ delete can cause a hell lot of **NullReferenceException**, **InvalidFormatException**, **FileNotFoundException** and many more which are headache! I hope you get my point :)